# Git - are these processes equal?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I would like to ask you what is the difference between two approaches.

Starting situation is:

```
master branch
|   
E  F - test branch
|  |
D  C
| /
B
|
A
```

**First approach:**

```
git checkout test
git merge master
git rebase -i master
git checkout master
git merge test
```

**Second approach:**

```
git checkout test
git rebase -i master
git checkout master
git merge test
```

What I wanted to do is squash C and F into one commit and then rebase it on master so it appears as one new commit on master.

But, I for experiment used first approach (normally using second) and it end up bad. Some changes which were on master was lost after using first approach.

So my question is what is difference? If I got it right after both approaches final graph should looks like:

```
master branch
|
G = C + F + old master
|   
E
|
D
|
B
|
A
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the final diagram, because `D` is shown twice.

Comment: @RichardFearn sorry that was mistake, I edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to say what the difference between the two approaches is without knowing exactly what you do during the interactive rebase.

But in the first approach, the merge will add a new commit (let's call it `M`) to the `test` branch. So immediately after the merge, the repo will look like this:

```
master branch
|
|  M - test branch
|/ |
E  F
|  |
D  C
| /
B
|
A
```

(Note that `master` is unchanged.)

Now when you do the interactive rebase, git realises that only `C` and `F` (and not the merge commit, `M`) need to be applied to `master`. So without making any changes to the command/commit list in the rebase file, you end up with this:

```
master branch
|
E --- C --- F - test branch
|
D
|
B
|
A
```

(Again, note that `master` hasn't changed.)

During the interactive rebase, if you change `pick` to `squash`/`fix` for commit `F`, it will be merged into `C`. So you'll end up with:

```
master branch
|
E --- C+F - test branch
|
D
|
B
|
A
```

Finally, after merging `test` into `master`, you end up with:

```
E --- C+F - test / master branch
|
D
|
B
|
A
```

The difference between the two approaches is that the first approach creates a merge commit on the `test` branch that then disappears when `test` is rebased onto `master`.

Comment: sorry I did that merge, i forgot to write it in question. So your answer imply that if is something wrong on my master now, I did the interactive rebase (resolving conflict) wrong.

Comment: Not sure about that. As I said, the rebase shouldn't be taking away anything from `master`, only adding new commits to it.

Answer (score 0):

Merging master into test an the rebasing makes no sense. As the changes on test are already there when you merge.

To achieve what you want you need to use --squash

1. Checkout test
2. Merge or rebase master (does not matter which one)
3. Checkout master
4. git merge test --squash
5. Commit with the message you want.

--squash squashes all your commits in test into one so in your history it would seem like one commit.